# Is it possible to have a list as a fact in prolog?

Tags: prolog

I am new to prolog an wanted to know if it is possible to have a list as a fact so i can use it with if, and, then.
For example:

```
list(a,b,c,d).
fact(x).
fact(y).

if x and y then list(a,b,c,d).
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can, but what you write makes no sense. A "Prolog program" is a list of implications *X <= A & ... & B* which determines which of your queries come back with `false` or a `true` (a constructive `true` as you get the values for variables making the query `true` as answer). So the idea of having a `if x and y then list(a,b,c,d)` does not really fit into this.. unless you want to say something like

```
foo([a,b,c,d]).   % This is true! List [a,b,c,d] has attribute "foo"
bar(a).           % This is true! The atom a has attribute "bar"
baz(b).           % This is true! The atom b has attribute "baz"

% A value for X has attribute "solution" if:
% 1) It has attribute bar
% 2) It is a member of any list that has attribute "foo"

solution(X) :- bar(X),foo(List),member(X,List).
```

```
?- solution(X).
```

will give `X=a`.